# If higher homotopy groups are trivial, then the fundamental group is a complete invariant?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two n-manifolds all of whose higher homotopy groups are trivial, and the first homotopy groups are isomorphic (but the existence of a mapping inducing an isomorphism is not assumed). Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent?

It seems to me I read somewhere about "the triviality of higher homotopy groups makes the fundamental group a complete invariant", but I can't remember where.

Comment: You forgot to assume that manifolds are connected. For CW complexes, such a homotopy-equivalence is Whitehead's theorem. But it is currently unknown if every topological manifold is homeomorphic to a CW complex. (The open case is in dimension 4.) It is a hard theorem that every manifold is homotopy-equivalent to a CW complex. Thus, the answer to your question is positive but nontrivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this was a completely classic fact (see for example http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Aspherical_manifolds). Should I accept this answer or delete the question?

Comment: Accept it. This is not math overflow and the question is interesting

Comment: @Elad OK, thanks!